# Creating a warning in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have created a patient data entry form in Microsoft Access. One of the fields it collects is Medical Record number. There is only one MR# per patient, no matter how many times they visit the office. I have made a separate query that looks at how many times a MR# is entered -as in, how often is the patient going to the doctor. I would like to create an alert so that if the occurrences of the MR# are over 3, it alerts the doctor.

However, I was unable to find any information online that gives me a start on how to code this warning.
Any tips or coding examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your medical record number is in a textbox named txtMedicalRecordNumber.

If you want to allow the doctor to enter the value and only present a warning, then put code like this behind the textbox's After_Update event

```
If Nz(DCount("MedicalRecordNumber", "MyTable", "MedicalRecordNumber = '" &  me.txtMedicalRecordNumber & "'"), 0) > 3 Then
    MsgBox "This record has been entered more than three times"
End If
```

You could also assign the results of the dCount to a variable and give the number of entries in  the message box.

If you want to prevent them from entering the medical record more than three times, use the Before_Update event and cancel the update.

```
If Nz(DCount("MedicalRecordNumber", "MyTable", "MedicalRecordNumber = '" &  me.txtMedicalRecordNumber & "'"), 0) > 3 Then
    MsgBox "This record has been entered more than three times"
    cancel = true
End If
```